# Why are the curves of the data samples connected by a line?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I am attaching my txt file, graph, and code. Can you please tell me what to change in this code, or why this third straight line is coming in my graph, because I only need two curve lines. In other software like xmgrace it's showing two curves only.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

deformation, potential = np.loadtxt("poten-Rf259.txt", unpack=True)
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.plot(deformation, potential, linewidth=1, color='b')
plt.xlabel("$deformation$")
plt.ylabel("potential")
plt.yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
0.60     1996.95397779
0.61     1995.35525840
0.62     1993.86701437
0.63     1992.48491231
0.64     1991.19969171
0.65     1990.00485364
0.66     1988.89605689
0.67     1987.86875188
0.68     1986.91599808
0.69     1986.03420343
0.70     1985.21922699
0.71     1984.46631470
0.72     1983.77171151
0.73     1983.13117131
0.74     1982.53983312
0.75     1981.99532235
0.76     1981.49445904
0.77     1981.03536392
0.78     1980.61563713
0.79     1980.23282155
0.80     1979.88357050
0.81     1979.56605195
0.82     1979.27790062
0.83     1979.01687947
0.84     1978.78288516
0.85     1978.57209950
0.86     1978.38399957
0.87     1978.21704688
0.88     1978.06886192
0.89     1977.93793974
0.90     1977.82377479
0.91     1977.72453886
0.92     1977.64028757
0.93     1977.56966186
0.94     1977.51247702
0.95     1977.46734438
0.96     1977.43305218
0.97     1977.40866283
0.98     1977.39347411
0.99     1977.38486567
1.00     1977.38198044
1.01     1977.38578333
1.02     1977.39435293
1.03     1977.40721066
1.04     1977.42425865
1.05     1977.44721979
1.06     1977.47357918
1.07     1977.50320577
1.08     1977.53535737
1.09     1977.56925776
1.10     1977.60496583
1.11     1977.64155671
1.12     1977.67899730
1.13     1977.71674843
1.14     1977.75457845
1.15     1977.79221495
1.16     1977.82838072
1.17     1977.86261243
1.18     1977.89473051
1.19     1977.92436517
1.20     1977.95062327
1.21     1977.97352605
1.22     1977.99387754
1.23     1978.01047267
1.24     1978.02233261
1.25     1978.03018886
1.26     1978.03434229
1.27     1978.03431686
1.28     1978.02782602
1.29     1978.01489388
1.30     1977.99620759
1.31     1977.97164846
1.32     1977.94011930
1.33     1977.90108165
1.34     1977.85474975
1.35     1977.80116069
1.36     1977.73920528
1.37     1977.66702371
1.38     1977.58440415
1.39     1977.49291347
1.40     1977.39203011
1.41     1977.28170103
1.42     1977.16108588
1.43     1977.02866014
1.44     1976.88410316
1.45     1976.72847328
1.46     1976.56259216
1.47     1976.38386074
1.48     1976.20047863
1.49     1976.00349668
1.50     1975.79062208
1.51     1975.56427272
1.52     1975.32369916
1.53     1975.06525907
1.54     1974.78917861
1.55     1974.49730653
1.56     1974.19357061
1.57     1973.87528322
1.58     1973.54134915
1.59     1973.19101633
1.60     1972.82834582
1.61     1972.45110208
1.62     1972.05553210
1.63     1971.64144442
1.64     1971.20783885
1.65     1970.75735680
1.66     1970.29140464
1.67     1969.81219620
1.68     1969.31582059
1.69     1968.80021418
1.70     1968.26283644
1.71     1967.70510563
1.72     1967.13020137
1.73     1966.53988789
1.74     1965.93070810
1.75     1965.30035432
1.76     1964.64993511
1.77     1963.98214335
1.78     1963.29607120
1.79     1962.58677705
1.80     1961.85278252
1.81     1961.10290054
1.82     1960.33687553
1.83     1959.54927874
1.84     1958.74001445
1.85     1957.90788391
1.86     1957.05397043
1.87     1956.17614396
1.88     1955.26999324
1.89     1954.33375080
1.90     1953.37236582
1.91     1952.38212458
1.92     1951.35983354
1.93     1950.30220457
1.94     1949.20603907
1.95     1948.05714844
1.96     1946.84779027
1.97     1945.58008527
1.98     1944.23420931
1.99     1942.79805826
2.00     1941.26241606
2.01     1939.59635092
2.02     1937.76411055
2.03     1935.72007499
2.04     1933.39927526
2.05     1930.72795563
2.06     1927.60977402
2.07     1923.90784077
2.08     1919.45804354
2.09     1914.31285484

0.60     1998.69655342
0.61     1997.10205960
0.62     1995.61774169
0.63     1994.23972037
0.64     1992.95788603
0.65     1991.76641764
0.66     1990.66090368
0.67     1989.63677721
0.68     1988.68674207
0.69     1987.80810777
0.70     1986.99582463
0.71     1986.24553783
0.72     1985.55344269
0.73     1984.91507367
0.74     1984.32536754
0.75     1983.78293400
0.76     1983.28383613
0.77     1982.82671380
0.78     1982.40862045
0.79     1982.02768397
0.80     1981.67975264
0.81     1981.36364770
0.82     1981.07656995
0.83     1980.81699835
0.84     1980.58410256
0.85     1980.37438858
0.86     1980.18712107
0.87     1980.02126097
0.88     1979.87363292
0.89     1979.74345272
0.90     1979.62995824
0.91     1979.53135472
0.92     1979.44772023
0.93     1979.37757311
0.94     1979.32104058
0.95     1979.27599816
0.96     1979.24203421
0.97     1979.21798198
0.98     1979.20293129
0.99     1979.19417215
1.00     1979.19165696
1.01     1979.19541560
1.02     1979.20395824
1.03     1979.21615707
1.04     1979.23320721
1.05     1979.25599428
1.06     1979.28171220
1.07     1979.31101088
1.08     1979.34264374
1.09     1979.37618654
1.10     1979.41145970
1.11     1979.44782160
1.12     1979.48476237
1.13     1979.52196027
1.14     1979.55904133
1.15     1979.59588083
1.16     1979.63104564
1.17     1979.66430513
1.18     1979.69566099
1.19     1979.72388637
1.20     1979.74966849
1.21     1979.77150493
1.22     1979.79086274
1.23     1979.80610500
1.24     1979.81670006
1.25     1979.82369958
1.26     1979.82686535
1.27     1979.82547672
1.28     1979.81769448
1.29     1979.80330511
1.30     1979.78339939
1.31     1979.75736288
1.32     1979.72409901
1.33     1979.68352105
1.34     1979.63566920
1.35     1979.58069993
1.36     1979.51670517
1.37     1979.44233796
1.38     1979.35779846
1.39     1979.26468767
1.40     1979.16177621
1.41     1979.04976449
1.42     1978.92676326
1.43     1978.79213218
1.44     1978.64555037
1.45     1978.48837015
1.46     1978.32011092
1.47     1978.14017085
1.48     1977.95500440
1.49     1977.75460116
1.50     1977.53929775
1.51     1977.31056663
1.52     1977.06737359
1.53     1976.80606527
1.54     1976.52721955
1.55     1976.23286883
1.56     1975.92682410
1.57     1975.60574409
1.58     1975.26801315
1.59     1974.91469758
1.60     1974.54947451
1.61     1974.16923372
1.62     1973.77070376
1.63     1973.35355306
1.64     1972.91665268
1.65     1972.46280943
1.66     1971.99372187
1.67     1971.51115360
1.68     1971.01142423
1.69     1970.49285180
1.70     1969.95210065
1.71     1969.39103370
1.72     1968.81236301
1.73     1968.21808006
1.74     1967.60511707
1.75     1966.97077175
1.76     1966.31642577
1.77     1965.64473808
1.78     1964.95488565
1.79     1964.24169727
1.80     1963.50348643
1.81     1962.74968760
1.82     1961.97913235
1.83     1961.18709132
1.84     1960.37331514
1.85     1959.53686374
1.86     1958.67882118
1.87     1957.79696651
1.88     1956.88661558
1.89     1955.94582437
1.90     1954.97949954
1.91     1953.98399101
1.92     1952.95610229
1.93     1951.89377598
1.94     1950.79298520
1.95     1949.63969262
1.96     1948.42603486
1.97     1947.15347382
1.98     1945.80171537
1.99     1944.35916231
2.00     1942.81707081
2.01     1941.14446913
2.02     1939.30723411
2.03     1937.25876976
2.04     1934.93414618
2.05     1932.25762526
2.06     1929.13222293
2.07     1925.42169053
2.08     1920.96503220
2.09     1915.81720928
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply because you are plotting one line for one set of x,y data, not two lines; hence the one line has to join all points. Try

```
 p.scatter(deformation, potential, s = 2,  color='b')
```

and see your data as it should be shown. As these are data points this is more appropriate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

- The issue is `'poten-Rf259.txt'` contains two separate datasets, separated by an empty row, and `plt.plot` connects all of the points by a line, as there's no way to recognize the data are separate.
- `numpy.loadtxt` has `skiprows`, but this parameter doesn't seem to have a good implementation for skipping "sections" of rows.
- Alternatively, `pandas.read_csv` has `skiprows`, which will accept ranges of rows (e.g. `skiprows=range(151, 302)`)
- The benefit of loading the data, in a way that separate sets can be identified, is analysis is easier.
- The other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76394768/7758804) does not enable the creation of separate **line** plots.
- `pandas` uses `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend, and `numpy` is a dependency.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.3`, `pandas 2.0.1`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# load the first section of data, add column names, and a new column identifying the sample
df1 = pd.read_csv('d:/data/poten-Rf259.txt', sep='\\s+', header=None,
                  names=['deformation', 'potential'], skiprows=range(151, 302)).assign(sample=1)

# load the second section of data, add column names, and a new column identifying the sample
df2 = pd.read_csv('d:/data/poten-Rf259.txt', sep='\\s+', header=None,
                  names=['deformation', 'potential'], skiprows=range(0, 151)).assign(sample=2)

# combine the dataframes
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

# create a figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))

# iterate through each sample and plot it
for sample, data in df.groupby('sample'):
    data.plot(x='deformation', y='potential', ax=ax, ylabel='potential', label=f'Sample {sample}')
```

[image]

- `df1` and `df2` can also be plotted onto the same figure.

```py
ax = df1.plot(x='deformation', y='potential', label='Sample 1', figsize=(5, 4))
df2.plot(x='deformation', y='potential', label='Sample 2', ax=ax)
```

### Plot with `seaborn`

- `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib` and plots data easily from a long-form

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4))
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='deformation', y='potential', hue='sample', palette='tab10', ax=ax)
```